# Problems with converting strings and ints

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, console

I am new to c# developing and I am trying to create a car console application. The part I am having a struggle with is, I am creating a list that lets the user input the value of the cars and once the user is done he/she should just be able to hit enter to display the value of all the cars added up.

Here is the error from the compiler:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Here is the code from where i am getting the error:

```
Console.Clear();
List<int> myCars = new List<int>();

Console.WriteLine("Enter the car into the lot");
int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
myCars.Add(input);

while (input.ToString() != "") //The != is not equal to 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter another integer: ");
    input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); //This doesent work I dont know why
    int value;
    if (!int.TryParse(input.ToString(), out value))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Something happened I dont know what happened you figure it out I dont want to");
    }
    else
    {
        myCars.Add(value);
    }
}

if (input.ToString() == "Done")
{
    int sum = 0;
    foreach (int value in myCars)
    {
        sum += value;
        Console.WriteLine("The total of all the cars on the lot are : " + " " + value.ToString());
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/PYVofI here is a working solution.

Comment: I Parsed twice because it was saying that input cannot be converted into an int. So do i have to change the list to a string? or how do I change the readLine to read int?

Comment: From stdin you can read just strings. So you always need to convert string to int.

Comment: Thanks!!! I see were i went wrong

Answer (score 0):

The error is because "Done" can't be parsed into integer.
You also have some semantic mistakes. Here's the corrected code :

```
        Console.Clear();
        List<int> myCars = new List<int>();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the car into the lot");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        int IntValue;
        if (int.TryParse(input, out IntValue))
        {
            myCars.Add(IntValue);
        }

        while (input != "Done") //The != is not equal to 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter another integer: ");
            input = Console.ReadLine();

            if (int.TryParse(input, out IntValue))
            {
                myCars.Add(IntValue);
            }

        }

        int sum = 0;
        foreach (int value in myCars)
        {
            sum += value;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The total of all the cars on the lot are : " + " " + sum.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

The Int32.Parse() method, which you use, throws a FormatException in case you try to parse a value that is not an integer e.g. a string ("Done" in your case)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx

You should use Int32.TryParse() which returns false in case your parsing fails
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx